# JS. Как получить бинарный файл через fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

JS. Как получить бинарный файл через fetch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так

```
fetch(path)
    .then(response => { 
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP ${response.status} - ${response.statusText}`);
        }
        return response.arrayBufferr();})
    .then(buffer => {
       console.log(buffer);
       ....
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Завтра проверю и отпишу, галочку поставлю)